# How secure is Tox really?

Tags: instant-messaging

I'm wondering. I've found it online and it looks promising and good. I wonder how secure Tox is in terms of anonymity and encryption. Is there any information about privacy issues such IP leaks etc.?

Comment: *my guess: WhatsApp for free*

Comment: I would google this instead of ask it here, for example: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12657891

Comment: Hey purefan, no lmgtfy comments ;)